# Cannot add foreign key constraint on vps server

Tags: php, laravel

so I use my project locally and run this code `php artisan migrate` everything works perfectly fine and my tables will be created

but when I move to my vps and do the same thing I get this error

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>     SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL
>     : alter table `mediables` add constraint `mediables_media_id_foreign` forei
>     gn key (`media_id`) references `media` (`id`) on delete cascade)

I followed some solution from this site but they didn't work

my migration file :

```
 Schema::create('media', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->nullable();
        $table->string('old_name')->nullable();
        $table->text('desc')->nullable();
        $table->string('category')->nullable();
        $table->string('type');
        $table->string('format');
        $table->string('href');
        $table->string('thumbnail')->nullable();

        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('mediables', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->integer('media_id')->nullable();
        $table->integer('mediable_id');
        $table->string('mediable_type');
        $table->primary(['media_id','mediable_id','mediable_type']);

        $table->timestamps();
    });
    Schema::table('mediables', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('media_id')
            ->references('id')->on('media')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

note that there is a polymorphic relation between media and other models in my project

the only difference between my local machine and my vps is that I have apache locally and nginx on vps if it's related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`media` table should have `id` column, because `media_id` references to it.

Also, if `id` is `increment()`, you should use `unsigned()` foreign key:

```
$table->integer('media_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
```

Comment: You still didn't add `unsigned()`

Answer (score 1):

if you're using new WAMP take care of it's mysql as it's by default will accept any relation even between non-existing columns like

```
$table->foreign('media_id')
        ->references('id')->on('media')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
```

the `id` isn't existing in `media` table.

Also `$table->primary(['media_id','mediable_id','mediable_type']);` won't run as you've already set a primary `id` as `$table->increments('id');` will set `id` as a primary.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set table engine to `InnoDB` by default or set it explicitly with

```
$table->engine = 'InnoDB';
```

Only the `InnoDB` engine handles foreign key constraints.